# Can't test libgdx Project

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, libgdx, junit4

I am busy with my project team writing a cross platform game using libgdx. I am trying to do the unit testing, currently I just imported classes and here is my code:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.mygdx.game.*;
import com.mygdx.game.input.TouchInputProcessor;


public class CarTest {

    Car car;
    World world;
    Vector2 vector;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        vector = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
        try {
            this.world = new World(vector, true);

            this.car = new Car(world, 2, 4, new Vector2(10, 10), (float) Math.PI,
                    60, 20, 60);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }

    […]

}
```

and we  get following error when running junit:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at CarTest.setUp(CarTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Unable to read file for extraction: gdx-box2d64.dll
```

how can i make my  setup function for test work? or better how do you unit test libgdx projects ?

Comment: Did you used Gradle to create the project?

Comment: yes, I used Gradle, finally I could test some classes by mocking with Mockito.

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependencies via testCompile in the project gradle script.

```
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my problem was that I added the box2d dependency only to the desktop project, but not to the core. This can make sense if you have not only a desktop version but also one for android or so which may require its own box2d library.

Anyway, I just added box2d to my core. If you have a setup targeting various platforms like described above, you can just add box2d to the core tests with testcompile like *Tejay* described.

```
testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```